# Как вывести дерево в качестве графа с активными стрелками?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Делаю просмотрщик для плана выполнения запроса *sql*. Нашел стиль для *TreeView*, который выводит дерево в виде вертикального графа, соединяя дочерние элементы с родительским простыми линиями.

Но мне нужно нечто иное. Нужно подобие оригинального средства просмотра из *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio*. Там это выглядит как на скрине. То есть:

- дочерний элемент с родителем соединяет не набор линий, а отдельная стрелка для каждого
- стрелки являются активными, то есть их можно выделять для просмотра информации, хотя сама информация берется из дочернего элемента, от которого эта стрелка идет к родителю

Меня интересует сам концепт, как такое реализуется. Первое, что мне пришло в голову - строить дерево в 2 этапа: строить узлы, потом поверх узлов уже строить стрелки отдельным слоем. В этом случае будет небольшая проблема с выделением (ведь дерева два, а выделен может быть только один узел либо стрелка). Да и в принципе этот метод больше походит на костыль.

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Не отображается скрин. В тегах сообщения текст со ссылкой на картинку есть, а в сообщении картинки не видно (

Comment: Возможно проще построить такой вывод в HTML и показывать.

Comment: @cpp_user, вряд ли это будет проще. Думал над этим. А еще думал над Canvas в качестве панели для TreeView (что, в общем то, почти то же самое), но размышления наперед привели меня к ряду подводных камней. Да и к тому же это курсовой проект, так что хотелось бы сделать готовое визуальное приложение, а не конвертер XML to HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на этот пример:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182683/NetworkView-A-WPF-custom-control-for-visualizing-a

Здесь происходит отрисовка и редактирование направленного графа, причём все элементы - и узлы, и стрелки - это элементы визуального дерева WPF, а значит можно, например, обрабатывать события  мыши на них.

Только вот стрелки тут по природе - прямые, а не как вам надо.

Comment: Пример не подходит. Стрелки не являются выделяемыми.